# VS 2022 change project variable like $(AssemblyName)

Tags: visual-studio-2022

How to change variables like `$(AssemblyName)`? I cannot find where they are defined.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defaults for these are defined in the SDK that your project uses.  For example, if your project file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Then you'll find these defined by the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props file that is part of that SDK.

The definition for `<AssemblyName>` defaults to your project name:

```
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(AssemblyName)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectName) 
</AssemblyName>
```

You can set this in your project file if you want it to be different from the default:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyName>WhateverNameIWant</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Expert tip: If you want to see everything that is defined in your project, you can see how MSBuild processes the file by running either of these commands (they're equivalent):

- `dotnet build -pp > out.txt`
- `msbuild /pp > out.txt`

Spoiler: there's *a lot* encapsulated in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip! The out.txt with `--pp` or `/pp` is very helpful